# Questions about constructing a child class that extends an abstract class constructor without super()

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am new to Java OOP and have been studying about this reading a GitBook called AP Computer Science in Java
I found this page very confusing:https://codehs.gitbooks.io/apjava/content/Classes-And-Object-Oriented-Programming/class-design-and-abstract-classes.html

the code is like this

```
public abstract class VehicleClass {
    private String type;
    private String vehicleName;

    public VehicleClass(String vType, String vName) {
        type = vType;
        vehicleName = vName;
    }

    /* This will need to be abstract, since 
     * we will need to implement different formulas
     * depending on if the vehicle is electric or 
     * gas powered.
     */ 
    public abstract double getMileage();
}

/* As you can see, in both classes, we have `getMileage` implemented
 * with different formulas.
 */ 
public class Truck extends VehicleClass {
    private double gasTankCapacity;
    private double milesPerTank;

    public Truck(double capacity, double miles) {
        gasTankCapacity = capacity;
        milesPerTank = miles;
    }

    public double getMileage() {
        return milesPerTank/gasTankCapacity;
    }
}

public class ElectricCar extends VehicleClass {
    private double maxCharge;
    private double milesPerCharge;
    private double maxEnergyUsage;

    public ElectricCar(double charge, double maxEnergy, double milesCharge) {
        maxCharge = charge;
        maxEnergyUsage = maxEnergy;
        milesPerCharge = milesCharge;
    }

    public double getMileage() {
        return (maxCharge*milesPerCharge)/maxEnergyUsage;
    }
}
```

MY questions are:
1. Why does he build the constructor of the two child classes without using `super()`. Doesn't he need to pass type and `vehicleName` to the super-class's constructor?
2. Why does he make type and `vehicleName` in the super-class to be `private`? I know that child class cannot inherit instances variables from the super class. Why doesn't he use protect instead?

Comment: 2)Most likely this is partial code of a project or more complete example you see later.  Generally you use private on anything you don't have a reason not to, because you don't want external classes to alter your internal state.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks however I still don't fully understand. if we use private for type, vehicleName, then the child classes cannot inherit these, so does that mean the child classes don't have a type and a vehicleName?

Comment: They do.  The child class just can't access it directly.  But it could call any functions defined in the parent that manipulate or use those values that are visible to it (as could outside code that uses the child class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, and it doesn't compile for that reason.

You may only omit parameterless calls to super, if there is such a constructor in the super class, in which case it is automatically inferred.

Speculation about the reason: The author wanted to show something else (as stated in the comments), maybe first had a working solution but then decided, that the vtype code bloated the example too much up and removed it, without testing again.

To Q.2, why does he make type and vehicleName in the superclass to be private?

I would say, you inherit instance variables, private or not, you just don't have direct access to them.

> Why doesn't he use protect instead?

We can't tell. Since it is only demo code, and the private members aren't used and not accessible via getter or setter, we just can't tell. Maybe it is an example which is later extended and then they get used?

Answer (score 3):

1. You are totally right! That code will not compile.
2. It's hard to say without knowing the purpose of those variables and of the class.